# GASで前日にリマインドメールを送るスクリプトを組みたい

Tags: google-apps-script

当方、音楽イベントのサイトを運営しておりまして、GASとWordPressの「Contact form7」というプラグインを連携（連携はプラグインでもう済んでいます）させて、「フォームから送られてきた日程に対して、前日にリマインドメールを送る」というスクリプトを組んでリマインドメールを自動化したいのですが、ネットで調べた限り、それらしいものがなく、また近いものでスクリプトを組んでやってみたのですが、どうしても自分が考えているようなものにならず。。どなたかご教授いただけないでしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。

具体的に以下のような形式で考えております。

・「Contact form7」から来たメアドにスクリプトに直書きした文章を「前日に」送る

ちなみに、当方のスペックは、GASの技術は素人でコピペで動かせる程度、ギリギリ一部修正してカスタマイズができるか、程度です。

Comment: > `スクリプトを組んでやってみたのですが、どうしても自分が考えているようなものにならず` 現状のコードを[編集]から追記すると、回答が集まりやすくなるかと存じます。

Comment: GASのフォームに日付や連絡先e-mail等を入力してもらって、その内容をスプレッドシートに記録していく。スプレッドシートの内容を定期的（毎日定時）にチェックして、日付が翌日になっているデータの連絡先にメールを送る。というのが素直な実装のように感じられます。Wordpressとの連携は必要なのですか？　連携するシステムが増えるほど、プログラミングの量も管理の手間も増えるので、なるべくシンプルな構成にすることをお勧めします。